# 'yet to collect' is this correct or not?

Tags: expressions

I have to specify not yet collected whether I can specify 'yet to collect' or 'yet to be collected' which one I can use?

Comment: What about "not collected"?

Comment: Is this a label in a GUI or something?  *Uncollected*

Comment: I cant use a negative word.

Comment: "To be collected"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

they're both fine, but I think "yet to be collected" is better. Also, the comments are also correct - "Uncollected" and "Not collected" are fine.